# Upload multiple documents with same field name using form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I wants to upload mulitple documents(PDF,doc, txt etc,...) with same field name using form submit in html.
I have tried everything with [PHP 5 File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) from w3schools.com.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
<div class="left">
    <h2>Detail 1</h2>
        Name:<input type="text" name="txtName[]"><br>
        Card No:<input type="text" name="txtCardNo[]"><br>
        Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="txtBdate[]"><br>
        Document:<input type="file" name="docs[]"><br>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <h2>Detail 2</h2>
        Name:<input type="text" name="txtName[]"><br>
        Card No:<input type="text" name="txtCardNo[]"><br>
        Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="txtBdate[]"><br>
        Document:<input type="file" name="docs[]"><br>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <h2>Detail 3</h2>
        Name:<input type="text" name="txtName[]"><br>
        Card No:<input type="text" name="txtCardNo[]"><br>
        Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="txtBdate[]"><br>
        Document:<input type="file" name="docs[]"><br>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But I dont know how to pass these multiple documents into form submit function. I have wrote above same code in [This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdwg0djj/) and need to submit this using javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload multiple files using php function with the loop to count total files and data as shown below (Codeigniter Insert)

```
    if(!empty($_POST['txtName'])){              
         for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['txtName']); $i++){
             $cont['name'] = $_POST['txtName'][$i];
             $cont['cardno'] = $_POST['txtCardNo'][$i];
             $cont['dob'] = $_POST['txtBdate'][$i];              
             $cont['docs'] = str_replace(' ', '_',$_FILES['docs']['name'][$i]);

            if($cont['docs'] != "")
            {                   
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["docs"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_path.$cont['docs']);

            }
            $this->db->insert('detail',$cont);

         }
         return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the multiple attribute of file element, it will allow you to select multiple files.Also your from is missing the enctype.

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="left">
        <h2>Detail 1</h2>
            Name:<input type="text" name="txtName[]"><br>
            Card No:<input type="text" name="txtCardNo[]"><br>
            Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="txtBdate[]"><br>

    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <h2>Detail 2</h2>
            Name:<input type="text" name="txtName[]"><br>
            Card No:<input type="text" name="txtCardNo[]"><br>
            Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="txtBdate[]"><br>

    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <h2>Detail 3</h2>
            Name:<input type="text" name="txtName[]"><br>
            Card No:<input type="text" name="txtCardNo[]"><br>
            Date of Birth:<input type="text" name="txtBdate[]"><br>

    </div>
    <div>
        Documents: <input type="file" name="docs" multiple="true"><br>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Try to add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute on the form tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still i need to submit all these fields and files together into single submit function that is what i want here in this question.

Comment: Have you tried this enctype="multipart/form-data"  ??

Comment: Yes, I have added it into form element as you have suggested.